# Can I use just one SQL query for auto increment and unique constraint?

Tags: sql, database, unique, auto-increment

I have an SQL database. A table in the database contains a column which is ID. I want to write an SQL query that alters that table so the values for ID column are automatically incremented (ID is integer), starting from say 1. So, I already have a table with ID column, I just want to write a query to alter it so the values for ID column are automatically inserted. 
Another column in the same table should have unique values (but is not primary key, primary key is ID), so I need to alter the table for that too. Can I cover this all with only one query?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you would use the AUTO_INCREMENT property on columns, SQL Server has the Identity property on columns, Oracle (and SQL Server 2012) has the SEQUENCE object.

With the MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT property you declare that the column has this property when you CREATE the table.  See here for more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

For the SQL Server Identity you give an option seed and increment value to the column property again when you CREATE the table.  See the BOL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(v=sql.80).aspx

Oracle has SEQUENCE objects (these were added to SQL Server in the 2012 version, so SQL Server 2012 has both Identity and SEQUENCE objects).  SEQUENCE is its own object and lives outside of the table, this is really nice if you want to use one value to manage many tables.  For Oracle SEQUENCE see this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm For SQL Server 2012 see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

See here for more info about Auto Increments across the different platforms: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Answer (score 0):

I thought you *couldn't* do that in a single *statement* in MySQL; you can always do it in a single transaction.

```
create table test (
  id integer not null,
  primary key (id),
  other_column char(1) not null
  );

begin;
alter table test
modify column id integer not null auto_increment;

alter table test 
add constraint unique (other_column);
commit;
```

But it turns out that MySQL's ALTER TABLE statement takes multiple "alter specifications". So this single statement does work.

```
alter table test
modify column id integer not null auto_increment,
add constraint unique (other_column);
```

[MySQL's syntax diagram for ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)...

```
ALTER [ONLINE | OFFLINE] [IGNORE] TABLE tbl_name
    [alter_specification [, alter_specification] ...]
    [partition_options]
```

The part that reads "[alter_specification [, alter_specification] ...]" makes multiple modifications in a single statement a winner for you.